# How to modify start orb with resource editor?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, resources

I tried xneditor, resource editor, resource hacker, resource builder, and a few other programs to edit my explorer.exe. I simply draw over orb bmps to test the idea first. Some of resource editors cant even open explorer, others cant save(gave errors), and anothers can save, but then it shows an error message instead of run! The closest result I get with resource builder - it opend, saved and then didnt gave any errors when I run my modified explorer.exe. But still when Im replacing files in windows folder and restart process or reboot the system it give blank screen. Arghh.

As I read [on this topic](https://superuser.com/questions/1297387/how-to-modify-a-resource-in-exporer-exe)  you cant run edited explorer.exe, but on other forums I also have read kind of tutorials where local ts modify their explorer with restorator or something and teaching it. 
I dont want to use malware cracked soft so I didnt try restorator. Also I coulndt find and orb changer without being heavly infected (I check here https://www.hybrid-analysis.com/).

**1) Does anybody know how to edit explorer resources and then  successfully run it on Win 7 x64?**

**2) Any free orb changer without viruses?**

Any help would be appreciated, cuz Im going crazy! :)

Comment: Do you mean the Windows 7 Start Icon?